# Por que construtores em delphi/pascal não podem ser privados como acontece em C++

Tags: c++, delphi

Existe algum motivo pelo qual não posso deixar um constructor em delphi como privado?

Comment: Como você vai construir o objeto se o constructor for privado?

Comment: @EMBarbosa, em C++ a visibilidade do construtor pode ser privada, e internamente não vejo motivos para esse recurso não ser permitido em delphi/pascal, isso atrapalha muito quando precisamos criar um objeto singleton, porque o construtor sempre fica exposto, é claro que utilizamos truques para contornar isso mas não é de forma alguma elegante.

Comment: Desconheço uma situação em que isso que descreveu pode atrapalhar... Mas talvez queira verificar essa questão e suas respostas aqui http://stackoverflow.com/a/5392736/460775

Comment: Ahh... agora que vi que já tinha feiro a pergunta no SOen e recebido basicamente a mesma resposta. http://stackoverflow.com/q/36535704/460775

Comment: @EMBarbosa, Se você ler bem os comentários da minha pergunta no stackoverflow-en vai chegar a conclusão que não há possibilidades de esconder construtores em delphi, vc pode fazer truques utilizando overloading, mas o método create sempre fica disponível, justamente o que questionei é o porque de não poder alterar a visibilidade do construtor, posso fazer isso em java, c++ mas não em pascal. O que eu quis dizer que "atrapalha"  é que vc tem de utilizar truques para conseguir fazer um singleton, legal o exemplo que vc postou mas utilizando interfaces e sessão crítica?

Comment: @EMBarbosa olha em C++: 

class Logger{
public:
   static Logger* Instance();
   bool openLogFile(std::string logFile);
   void writeToLogFile();
   bool closeLogFile();

private:
   Logger(){};  // Private so that it can  not be called
   Logger(Logger const&){};             // copy constructor is private
   Logger& operator=(Logger const&){};  // assignment operator is private
   static Logger* m_pInstance;
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao contrário do que você mencionou, você pode declarar um construtor privado em Delphi. Veja, o código abaixo simplesmente funciona:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas';

//var Foo: Tfoo2;
begin
  try
//    Foo := Tfoo2.CreatePrivado(1);
    TFoo2.FA := 'hello world';
    writeln(Foo.FA);
    readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

---

```
unit Unit1;

interface

type Tfoo2 = class(TObject)
     private
       constructor CreatePrivado(i:integer);
     public
       class var FA: string;
//       constructor Create(bar:Boolean);
     end;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils;

//constructor Tfoo2.Create(bar:Boolean);
//begin
//  inherited Create;
//  FA := 'bar';
//end;


constructor Tfoo2.CreatePrivado(i: integer);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FA := IntToStr(i);
end;

end.
```

Em Delphi, construtores podem ser herdados. Isso não acontece em Java, C# ou C++ por exemplo. Além disso, uma classe pode ter múltiplos construtores e eles podem também ter nomes diferentes. Geralmente chamados `Create`. Mas isso é só uma convenção e não uma regra.

Ainda mais, todas as classes em Delphi herdam em última instância de da classe `TObject`. Essa classe contém um construtor sem parâmetros chamado `Create`.

Assim, é fácil entender porque todas as classes em Delphi possuem o construtor sem parâmetros chamado `Create`.

Se você precisa esconder o construtor `Create` já mencionado, tente uma resposta de uma das seguintes perguntas no SOen:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14003208/460775

https://stackoverflow.com/q/5392107/460775

https://stackoverflow.com/q/14003153/460775

Parte da resposta é baseada em:
http://www.yanniel.info/2011/08/hide-tobject-create-constructor-delphi.html

Comment: depois teste o exemplo da sua resposta chame o create e ele ainda está desponível exemplo foo2 :=  Tfoo2.Create;

Comment: @WellingtonSilvaRibeiro Eu não disse que não estava. Você leu os links que passei? Você está misturando as coisas. Uma coisa é construtores não poderem ser privados, outra é você esconder o construtor Create. Qual é o objetivo de sua pergunta?

Comment: minha questão ainda é sobre visibilidade de constructor, algum deles sempre fica vívivel, a minha pergunta é se existe algum motivo estrutural no delphi para não permitir que eu seja impedido de chamar o create na instancia, o seu exemplo de fato compila mas do que adianta eu ter um constructor inventado se ainda posso chamar o create. Eu nunca disse que não sabia como fazer um singleton conforme está nos links, a minha queixa é que em delphi temos que utilizar truques para conseguir um resultado que em java ou c++ seria muito mais simples.

Comment: @WellingtonSilvaRibeiro desculpe, mas eu não disse que você não sabe. Também não disse que não precisa fazer nada. O que eu questionei é que minha resposta já responde sua pergunta como está. Não tenho mais nada a acrescentar em como a pergunta está no momento.

Answer (score 0):

Pra ser sincero com você Delphi tem sim métodos Private para um Construtor sim, quando uma linguagem é dita que é Orientada ela deve seguir a base dos pilares da POO (Encapsulamento, Abstração, Herança e Polimorfismo) acredito que para isso você deva declarar antes da utilização da mesma

```
type Class declaration
...
Constructor Name; {Overload;}
...
end;
```

---

```
type Class declaration
...
Constructor Name(Arguments); {Overload;}
...
end;
```

Espero ter te ajudado pelo menos um pouco :/

Comment: realmente os pilares de uma linguagem orientada a objetos é herança, polimorfismo, abstração e encapsulamento, entretanto meu questionamento é sobre visibilidade você não pode colocar um construtor em delphi/pascal como privado, em TObject o construtor não é virtual. Essa peculiaridade afeta em como vc aplica o design orientado a objetos segundo os padrões de projetos conhecido tais como citei no comentário da pergunta.